# MVC Browser Back Button Issue After Logout In MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Good Day  hi

```
     After logout when i press browser back button again the home page is shown
```

one solution is there in Global.asax file i can write like this

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
```

This will solve my problem but i dont want to use it

so i tried using this code on the layout page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            CheckingSeassion();
        });
        function CheckingSeassion() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ClearSession", "Login")';,
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.d == 0) {
                        window.location = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Login")';;
                    }
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

but this method works but the home page is still being shown .
When i click some button in th then i am being brought to login page

how do i solve this issue i think the page is begin cached

Comment: Fyi (and off-topic): It's spelled Session. On-topic: Why is it a problem that the homepage is cached? If you press back, it is normal behavior for a browser to use a (client) cached version.

Comment: on thing you can as to disable back button of browser with javascript

Comment: i think this is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to disable back button(with some javascript) is :

```
<script>
 function preventBack(){ window.history.forward(); }
 setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
 window.onunload=function(){ null };
</script>
```

Comment: Where do i write this code  in the login page or Layout page ?

Comment: OK :) let me try this

Comment: no it is still showing me that page when i press back button

Comment: @suraj..try it on layout page then

Comment: try opening more than 3 page and then press log out button and then check :)

Comment: I tried it on Layout page then the browser back button doesnt work if i press back button it brings me back again to that page is it possible that functionality to work on login page what you have given me it works

Comment: No :( is there any way to clear the history i did some thing  like this     using html 5   history.pushState this line will put log out page in the history                function preventBack() {
            //   alert("hi");
           //  alert(window.history.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
                history.pushState(null, "Login", '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Login")');
            }
            window.history.forward();

        }
        setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
        window.onunload = function () { null };

Comment: @suraj...html5.. will not solve your problem because today also many versions of browser doesn't support html 5...just provide some detail what you want exactly because above code is working perfectly....

Comment: what i want is when the user logs out and if he presses browser back button then he must not see the previous page at all but that previous page will be shown as it is cached i want to avoid that